# iOS Release App crashes on Launch "Unable to get pid for label"

Tags: ios, react-native

Disclaimer: I am not using Expo.

```
react: 16.8.3
react-native: 0.59.9
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
iOS 12.2 (16E227)
```

I have this weird problem with my React Native iOS app that has been happening for a while. **At a first glance everything works as excepted**, both Development and Release. I am able to install it in my device and use it without the metro server running.

**However after some time**, like couple of days the app in my phone won't launch, it crashes at the launch screen, the one that says "Powered by React Native ..." with the following errors showing up in the console:

```
Process: assertiond

Failed to start job with error <NSError: 0x103e56f70; domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain; code: 3; reason: "No such process"> {
    description = "Unable to get pid for label UIKitApplication:org.josemigallas.RealmsCounter[0x953c][62]";
    failureReason = "No such process";
    userInfo = {
        BKLaunchdJobLabel = UIKitApplication:org.josemigallas.RealmsCounter[0x953c][62];
        BKLaunchdOperation = launch_get_running_pid_4SB;
    }
}
```

```
Process: SpringBoard

[org.josemigallas.RealmsCounter] Bootstrap failed with error: <NSError: 0x2830c26a0; domain: BKSProcessErrorDomain; code: 1 (bootstrap-failed); reason: "Failed to start job">
```

```
Process: SpringBoard

Bootstrapping failed for <FBApplicationProcess: 0x1371b5470; org.josemigallas.RealmsCounter; pid: -1> with error: Error Domain=BKSProcessErrorDomain Code=1 "Unable to bootstrap process with bundleID org.josemigallas.RealmsCounter" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to bootstrap process with bundleID org.josemigallas.RealmsCounter, BKSProcessExitReason=0, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Failed to start job, NSUnderlyingError=0x2830c0210 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=3 "No such process" UserInfo={BKLaunchdOperation=launch_get_running_pid_4SB, NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to get pid for label UIKitApplication:org.josemigallas.RealmsCounter[0x953c][62], BKLaunchdJobLabel=UIKitApplication:org.josemigallas.RealmsCounter[0x953c][62], NSLocalizedFailureReason=No such process}}, BKSProcessJobLabel=UIKitApplication:org.josemigallas.RealmsCounter[0x953c][62], BSErrorCodeDescription=bootstrap-failed}
```

Is this a bug? Or did I do something wrong with the Xcode configuration? The React Native documentation is of no use Xcode wise and so is iOS's because this is something in between of both.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say React I'm inclined to think you are developing a progressive web app? If you are, it may be a state problem with iOS (which doesn't store state). And this can be tested by going to the URL in safari (which should work).

Comment: It's React Native so nothing to do with browser in this case

Comment: In that case sorry I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, turned out it as simple as the provisioning profile is only valid for 6 days without a paid Apple Developer account... The app will work during the first days then inevitably it won't start anymore and it has to be rebuild again.

Comment: Same issue here as a release version of flutter, sign. I don't understand why Apple has such a limitation, it took me a whole day to figure out the reason and I have to change my build to debug mode.